# Use __init_subclass__ for implementation checking

Tags: python, init, metaclass

I have a project where I have a base class and a bunch of derived classes. Really mostly to make sure that I don't forget anything I want to impleput in place some sort of method implementation checking. I am wondering if this makes sense, and whether there are any potential conflicts with inheritance.

```
class Base:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__()
        for prop in ['prop_to_check']:  # extend this list for additional properties to check
            if not hasattr(cls, prop):
                raise NotImplementedError(f'{prop} is not implemented on {cls.__name__}')

class Derived(Base):
    prop_to_check = 3
    pass

class Derived2(Base):
    pass

Derived() 
Derived2()
```

Cheers
Fabian

Comment: Any reason why you aren't using the [`abc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) module?

Comment: Not a good reason probably :) Have watched a video about __init_subclass__ first :D

Answer (score 1):

The only downside is readability. To subclass your class, one has to read (and understand) the `__init_subclass` function. On the other hand, you could just write

```
class Base(abc.ABC):

   @abc.abstractproperty
   def x(self):
       """children MUST implement this"""
```

Comment: seems indeed easier. What if Base had additional functionality? Would my Base have to be derived from a lets call it ABC_Base class? Or should the children be derived from ABC_Base?

Comment: would you want to instantiate the base class? or just implement some method to be inherited?

Comment: nope, base class would not be instantiated. The latter is the case, some methods to be inherited.

Comment: Then it works like abstract class in any other language. You *can* have implemented methods, but you can't instantiate it. you only instantiate subclasses that implement the abstract ones

Comment: thx, I shall look into it!

Is the decorator the same for methods, class-properties and properties alike?

i.e.
class Base(abc.ABC):
  x = 3

  def x(self):
     return 4

  @property
  def x(self):
      return 5

Comment: @FabianBosler: there's `abstractmethod, abstractclassmethod`, etc. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html

Comment: Thre is  "abstractproprety" - but it can't check for ordinary class attributes.

Comment: but the doc says abstractproperty is depreciated. Shouldn't the above code then not be changed to abstractmethod?